# How to avoid that a click inside table header fires click on the whole table header

Tags: angular, dom-events

I have the following table headers (columns) that allow sorting and editing

[image]

When clicking on the table header the sorting will change so I added this

```
(click) = "changeToNextSortOption(header)"
```

But there is also the funcionality to click on the table header name to edit it and for that I added this

```
(click)="editColumn(header.id, i, $event)"
```

But when the click on the column header is fired, the click event on the table header is also firing.

**I need to make sure that if the click on the header name is fired the other one is not fired (since it will change the table ordering), Please show me how to do that.**

Here is the component HTML part

```
<th
  [ngClass]="{ disabledTable: mutipleSelect }"
  *ngFor="let header of table.headers; let i = index"
  id="header{{ header.id }}"
  class="type{{ header.type }} ic-dgd handle"
  (mouseenter)="drgIcon = i; showDrgIcon = !showDrgIcon"
  (mouseleave)="drgIcon = -1; showDrgIcon = !showDrgIcon"
  [attr.data-id]="header.id"
  (click) = "changeToNextSortOption(header)"
>
  <i
    *ngIf="this.drgIcon == i && !creating && showDrgIcon == true"
    class="icon-collapseIn-Copy float-left"
  ></i>
  <i *ngIf="isSortDescending(header)" class="material-icons"
    >keyboard_arrow_down</i
  >
  <i *ngIf="isSortNone(header)" class="material-icons">remove</i>
  <i *ngIf="isSortAscending(header)" class="material-icons"
    >keyboard_arrow_up</i
  >
  <span
    (click)="editColumn(header.id, i, $event)"
    title="{{ header.title }}"
    >{{ header.title
    }}<i *ngIf="canEditTable" class="icon-edit-nocircle"></i
  ></span>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `event.stopPropagation()` in your child clickable element.

That means you can add this in `.ts` file like this:

```
editColumn(id: number, i: number, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...
}
```

*OR*

you can just add `; $event.stopPropagation()` code after handler in your template like this:

```
...
<span
    (click)="editColumn(header.id, i, $event); $event.stopPropagation()"
    title="{{ header.title }}"
    >{{ header.title
    }}<i *ngIf="canEditTable" class="icon-edit-nocircle"></i
  ></span>
...
```

P.S.: in some cases, you also need to add `$event.preventDefault();` additionally in the same way.

Comment: works great, I have used that in the past but forgot completly about it - thanks